# Solving complex improper integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-integration, trigonometric-integrals

> Evaluate the following integrals and show the details of your work.

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos^2\theta}{5 - 4\cos\theta}\, d\theta$$

So generally my approach is to find the roots because I need them to evaluate the residues which I can then use in the residue theorem.

So first thing's first is to find the roots...

The denominator factors to: $5(1-\frac{4\cos\theta}{5})$

But when does $\cos\theta = 5/4$ so that $1 - \frac{4 \cos \theta}{5} = 0$

My book says the answer is: $\frac{5\pi}{12}$ FWIW but I'm not sure how to get here.

Comment: If you want to apply "contour integration techniques" for it, first write the integrand as a function of $\mathbb{C}.$ Then find its singularities and residues at singularities inside your contour  (here the unit circle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac1z\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{z+1/z}2\right)^2}{5-4\frac{z+1/z}2}\\&=-\frac{(z^2+1)^2}{2(z-2)\left(z-\frac12\right)z^2}.\end{align}With this choice of $f$, and since$$(\forall\theta\in[0,2\pi]):\cos\theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}2,$$we have\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^2\theta}{5-4\cos\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta&=\frac1i\oint_{|z|=1}f(z)\,\mathrm dz\\&=2\pi\sum_{|\xi|<1}\operatorname{res}_{z=\xi}f(z)\\&=2\pi\left(\operatorname{res}_{z=0}f(z)+\operatorname{res}_{z=1/2}f(z)\right)\\&=2\pi\left(-\frac5{16}+\frac{25}{48}\right)\\&=2\pi\frac5{24}\\&=\frac{5\pi}{12}.\end{align}

Comment: It would be more clear if you add few details to explain him why this function $f$ coincides (on the unit circle) with the integrand in the OP.

Comment: @Bumblebee Done, but since the OP wrote “I need them to evaluate the residues which I can then use in the residue theorem”, I assumed that he knew the general method.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my request.

Comment: Yeah can you clarify?

Comment: Yeah why does $cos \theta = (z + 1/z)/2?$

Comment: What I wrote was that $\cos\theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}2$. Do you have a problem with this equality?

Comment: Ah I see, I saw this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--hW1I2CGv4

Comment: I'm still having trouble with the first two lines... where does 1/z come from?

Comment: and where does 1/i come from?

Comment: If you want to compute an integral of the type $\int_0^{2\pi}R(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$, you can define$$f(z)=\frac1zR\left(\frac{z+1/z}2,\frac{z-1/z}{2i}\right)$$and then\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}R(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta&=\frac1i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-i\theta}R\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}2,\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}\right)ie^{i\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\frac1i\oint_{|z|=1}f(z)\,\mathrm dz.\end{align}